# Why can this be value be cloned, but the same value doesn't satisfy a Clone trait bound?

Tags: rust

In the following [Rust playground code snippet](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=293e60c3c9082023a0944767d9febcf1), the function `bar` can have `.clone()` called without issue, thanks to some of the existing traits and trait impls in the same snippet.

However, when I try to pass it to a function that has a `Clone` requirement (`RandomTable::new().add(Box::new(bar))`), I get the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn Fn((&'a mut Box<i8>, i8)) -> i8: Clone` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:69:24
   |
69 |     RandomTable::new().add(Box::new(bar))
   |                        ^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `dyn Fn((&'a mut Box<i8>, i8)) -> i8`
   |
   = note: required for `Box<dyn Fn((&'a mut Box<i8>, i8)) -> i8>` to implement `Clone`
note: required by a bound in `RandomTable::<T>::add`
  --> src/main.rs:36:8
   |
36 |     T: Clone,
   |        ^^^^^ required by this bound in `RandomTable::<T>::add`
...
43 |     pub fn add(mut self, spawn: T) -> Self {
   |            --- required by a bound in this associated function
```

Here is the snippet, somewhat long due to some of the traits involved:

```rust
#![feature(tuple_trait)]

use std::marker::Tuple;

trait CloneableFn<A: Tuple, B>: Fn(A) -> B {
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<A, B>>
    where
        Self: 'a;
}

impl<A: Tuple, B, F: Fn(A) -> B + Clone> CloneableFn<A, B> for F {
    fn clone_box<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<A, B>>
    where
        Self: 'a,
    {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}

impl<'a, A: 'a + Tuple, B: 'a> Clone for Box<dyn 'a + CloneableFn<A, B>> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        (**self).clone_box()
    }
}


#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct RandomTable<T> {
    pub entries: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> RandomTable<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        RandomTable {
            entries: Vec::new()        }
    }

    pub fn add(mut self, spawn: T) -> Self {
        self.entries.push(spawn);
        RandomTable {
            entries: self.entries
        }
    }
}



fn foo(a: i8, b: i8) -> i8 {
    a + b
}

fn bar(args: (&mut Box<i8>, i8)) -> i8 {
  let ( a, b) = args;
  *a = Box::new(**a + 1);
  **a + b
}

type SimpleSpawner<'a> = dyn Fn((&'a mut Box<i8>, i8)) -> i8;

pub fn room_table_test<'a>(map_depth: i32) -> RandomTable<Box<SimpleSpawner<'a>>> {
    // DEBUG: remove this fn
    //let health_pot: Box<SimpleSpawner> = Box::new(health_potion); // type as function pointer
    RandomTable::new().add(Box::new(bar))
    //.add(shield(map_depth).spawn(), 10)
}



fn main() {
    let foo2 = foo.clone();
    println!("{}", foo2(2,3));
    let bar2 = bar.clone();
    
    
}
```

Comment: May I ask why are you using the internal-only feature `tuple_trait`, when you don't need it at all?

Comment: It cannot be called because of your traits, because it doesn't involve your traits at all (it's `dyn Fn`, not `dyn CloneableFn`. It can be cloned because you clone the function item, not the `dyn Fn`. Did you mean to store `Box<dyn CloneableFn>`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It seems to be needed when using `Tuple`, as in the definition of `CloneableFn`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you're right, that is what I needed; working example [shown here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=19151eabf239fd3859882376b0221e3a) . I thought `CloneableFn` would be automatically inferred for all ` Fn(A) -> B` where `A: Tuple`.

Comment: Of course I meant that you won't use `Tuple` too, as an internal-only trait.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I see - I hadn't realized it was internal and not just unstable, though. Also, thank you for pointing out I don't need it - at some point I was probably trying to manipulate the values in the tuple, but my current approach (in my wider code base) avoids that as well.

Comment: I also see the error of my ways with regard to the original question; `CloneableFn` requires `Clone`, which I'd forgotten as I hadn't looked at that closely for a while, and `SimpleSpawner` did not include it (nor can it directly as it is non-auto).